# Pass HashMap of fragments to bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using `HashMap` of fragment's backstack. To save backstack and current fragment I use the code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>> mStacks;
public static final String TAB_PROFILE  = "tab_profile";
public static final String TAB_DASHBOARD  = "tab_dashboard";
public static final String TAB_CHATS  = "tab_chats";
public static final String TAB_SETTINGS  = "tab_settings";

private String mCurrentTab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupViews();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentTab = savedInstanceState.getString("currentTab");
        mStacks = (HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("stacks");
    } else
        selectedTab(TAB_DASHBOARD);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("stacks", mStacks);
    outState.putString("currentTab", mCurrentTab);
}

private void setupViews() {
    mStacks = new HashMap<>();
    mStacks.put(TAB_PROFILE, new Stack<>());
    mStacks.put(TAB_DASHBOARD, new Stack<>());
    mStacks.put(TAB_CHATS, new Stack<>());
    mStacks.put(TAB_SETTINGS, new Stack<>());

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);


    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.action_dashboard);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);


    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_profile:
                selectedTab(TAB_PROFILE);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_dashboard:
                selectedTab(TAB_DASHBOARD);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_chats:
                selectedTab(TAB_CHATS);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                selectedTab(TAB_SETTINGS);
                return true;
        }
        return true;
    });

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(item -> {
        if (mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).size() != 1) {
            mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).clear();
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_profile:
                    selectedTab(TAB_PROFILE);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_dashboard:
                    selectedTab(TAB_DASHBOARD);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_chats:
                    selectedTab(TAB_CHATS);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    selectedTab(TAB_SETTINGS);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void selectedTab(String tabId) {
    mCurrentTab = tabId;

    if(mStacks.get(tabId).size() == 0){
        if(tabId.equals(TAB_PROFILE)){
            Fragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable("user", Globals.getCurrentUser());
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            pushFragments(tabId, fragment,true);
        } else if(tabId.equals(TAB_DASHBOARD)){
            pushFragments(tabId, new DashboardFragment(),true);
        }else if(tabId.equals(TAB_CHATS)){
            pushFragments(tabId, new GroupsFragment(),true);
        }else if(tabId.equals(TAB_SETTINGS)){
            pushFragments(tabId, new SettingsFragment(),true);
        }
    }else {
        pushFragments(tabId, mStacks.get(tabId).lastElement(),false);
    }
}

public void pushFragments(String tag, Fragment fragment, boolean shouldAdd){
    if(shouldAdd)
        mStacks.get(tag).push(fragment);
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}

public void popFragments(){
    Fragment fragment = mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).elementAt(mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).size() - 2);

    mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).pop();

    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).size() == 1){
        finish();
        return;
    }

    popFragments();
}
}
```

Set new fragments using

```
((MainActivity)context).pushFragments(MainActivity.TAB_CHATS, fragment,true);
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/background_material_light"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/waPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />
```

Everything works fine on screen rotation, but application crashes with exception on application hide.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value %FragmentName%{c985244 #2 id=0x7f090051}

As I read, it happens when one of the objects I'm trying to pass is not `Parceable`, but have no idea how to fix this. Any thoughts?

**UPD**

After I made all of my fragments `Serializable`, new exception throws

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = %FragmentName%)
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

**UPD2**

Seems like a found a solution - `transient` property. Now I'm trying to make all non-serializeable objects transient.

**UPD3**

It helped, but I don't know is it efficient enough.

Comment: implement Serializable on Fragment you are passing

Comment: it seems bundle needs all objects to be serialized which is impossible to have and may cause out of memory exception. so suggested to choose other way to fulfill your requirements otherwise making all objects serialized is difficult.

Comment: I would suggest not putting Fragments in the bundle in the first place.  It's just going to cause problems.

Comment: @Jahnold making my fragments serializeable and putting `transient` to required fields resolved my problem. Seem like. Have no idea how it works. Are there any other ways to save fragments?

Comment: Fragments are not meant to be serialized, and not meant to be put in a bundle. Keeping a map of Fragments is also bad idea most of the time.

Please use  something similar to `getSupportManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
.commit();` in order to maintain backstack.

Comment: @guness the problem is that I keep own backstack for every fragment on every page of `BottomNavigationView`

Comment: The system saves fragment states and their back stack so this is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @dominicoder but I need to restore fragment that was opened on specif tab when open it again. For that I need to store a fragment and it's backstack to restore it on tab button click.

Comment: There is no reason for you to be saving an entire Fragment to a Bundle. That's just wrong. Instead, your top level activity can add the fragments to the fragment manager. Each fragment can then build up it's own back stack. As you navigate via bottom navigation the activity can swap between the fragments. Their individual back stack states will be managed by the system.

Comment: @dominicoder can you write a little sample that shows your idea? If it really works I'll mark it as a solution.

Comment: Post your current Activity code. I can try to make suggestions based on that.

Comment: @dominicoder updated original post

Comment: @ahgpoug you can do this by using different backstacks with `.addToBackStack("CHATS") ` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my suggestion:

1. Your activity maintains a reference to the four fragments it wants for the bottom navigation toggling.
2. On toggling bottom navigation, you **replace** the current fragment in the **activity** fragment manager.
3. While on a given fragment, as you interact with the UI, you **push** things on to the **fragment** child fragment manager.

This way, each fragment maintains its own backstack automatically, you don't have to save any state, and it all Just Works™.

Some sample code that might help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Fragment mProfileFragment;
    private Fragment mDashboardFragment;
    private Fragment mChatsFragment;
    private Fragment mSettingsFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Init fragments
        }
        else {
            // Find last active fragments in fragment manager
        }

        setupViews();
    }

    private void setupViews() {
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.action_dashboard);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_profile:
                    fragment = mProfileFragment;
                    break;
                case R.id.action_dashboard:
                    fragment = mDashboardFragment;
                    break;
                case R.id.action_chats:
                    fragment = mChatsFragment;
                    break;
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    fragment = mSettingsFragment;
                    break;
            }

            // Replace the currently active fragment which will be
            // managing its own backstack
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frament_container, fragment)
                .commit();
        });
    }
}
```

And one of your fragments would push stuff on its own stack like this:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.id.fragment_layout, container, false);
        Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.some_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment someFragmentToPush = new SomeFragmentToPush();
                // Use the child fragment manager to keep UI
                // local to this fragment instance, adding to backstack
                // for automatic popping on pressing back
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragment_layout, someFragmentToPush)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried this and faced the problem, because I'm using static fragment layouts and inflate them using inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false); And when I call .replace method of FragmentManager, new fragment shows above the previous one. Also I can't return to the previous fragment by pressing back button. Is there any way to do this in my case?

Comment: .replace should literally replace the current one with the previous, you shouldn't see one on top of the other. To return to the previous fragment by pressing back you need to call addToBackStack in the activity framgment manager as well.

Comment: but it happens in my case. Next fragment appears above previous one even after `.replace` method.

Comment: You're sure you're `replacing` into the right container with the right arguments? Post some code please.